# Asp.net MVC website with ClickOnce applications on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, clickonce

I have an Asp.net MVC website that I deploy to an Azure Cloud service.
There, I need a ~/ClickOnce application from where customers can download applications.
Applications are constantly updated, so I can't deploy them as part of the Azure deployment package, but that should really be a folder that I can update on my own.

From my understanding, that folder will be cleaned up every time the web role is restarted.
I would need more a persisted local storage that I can manually update (even through remote desktop), and that should be available from the web site (http://mywebsite.cloudapp.net/ClickOnce/..).

Is there a way to map a local storage folder to a web site path?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a controller that serves the files:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "ClickOnce/{*fileName}",
    new { controller = "File", action = "GetFile", fileName = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "MyApp.Web.Controllers" }
);

// in FileController
public FilePathResult GetFile(string fileName)
{
    var dir = Server.MapPath("/local/storage/directory");
    var path = Path.Combine(dir, fileName);
    return File(path, GetMimeType(Path.GetExtension(fileName));
}

// see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228998.aspx 
private string GetMimeType(string extension)
{
    if (extension == ".application" || extension == ".manifest")
        return "application/x-ms-application";
    else if (extension == ".deploy")
        return "application/octet-stream";
    else
        return "application/x-msdownload";
}
```

If you think about it this has a great advantage:

ClickOnce Update locations are baked into the client so you can't changed that.

But with this simple setup you could return different versions for different clients. So maybe you want to role out your new version to some clients to test it in the wild. Or a customer may only update to a specific version unless he buys an update.

For this to work you have to keep every `.application` file for every version and just return the appropriate one.

```
customer1 request yourapp.application -> return yourapp-1.1.application
customer2 request yourapp.application -> return yourapp-1.2.application
```

Comment: In a web application deployed normally (on premises, as Azure Websites or in Azure Virtual Machines), this solution would be perfect because you can do partial content update. However in Azure Cloud Services (where OP is deploying the solution), this approach will not work because there you have to provide your complete application package to Azure and based on that Azure will deploy your application.

Comment: Well I am not very familiar with azure but you asked for a way to map a local storage folder to a web site path. And this method should work http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee758708.aspx - However, is it possible for you to host the ClickOnce files on a different location (maybe another azure role)? In that case you could stick with this controller and instead of returning a file you could `return Redirect("http://someotherserver.com/ClickOnce/" + fileName);`

Comment: Azure (especially Cloud Services) is a tricky business and it makes us rethink the way we have been doing web development. Technically you could host the ClickOnce file in a different Azure role but why do it when you have massively scalable cloud storage (blob storage that is) available to you. This is why I recommended using blob storage in my answer.

Comment: The suggested approach is good in meeting requirement for  ~/ClickOnce location. But the GetFile method implementation should indeed retrieve the package from Blob storage instead of the local folder, because it will be difficult to maintain local folder content when multiple instances of the web role needed.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking you could manually update the folder by connecting to your application instances using Remote Desktop Connection however **it is strictly not recommended** because of the stateless nature of Azure Cloud Services.

A better solution would be to **`host your ClickOnce deployment files in blob storage`**. That way you can update them independent of your application updates. Take a look at this blog post for more details: https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/how-to-host-a-clickonce-deployment-in-azure-blob-storage/.